# 'openArea' is not defined no-undef Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to convert HTML code into REACT so then I face this error that unexpected use of event.

The onClick is not working I think. I tried multiple attempts but nothing useful happened. Anyone, please help me to correct this.

> This is converted code but still it's not working

Markup:

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="desktop-tabs">
        <div className="tab">
            <button className="tablinks" onClick={"openArea(event, 'Low/Mid Back')"} id="defaultOpenClose">Low/Mid Back <i className="icofont-rounded-right"></i></button>
            <button className="tablinks" onClick={"openArea(event, 'Head and Neck')"} id="defaultOpenClose">Head and Neck <i className="icofont-rounded-right"></i></button>
            <div id="Low/Mid Back" className="tabcontent" onClick={"openArea(event, 'Low/Mid Back')"} id="defaultOpenClose">
                <ul className="list">
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Low Back Pain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Mid Back Pain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Bulging Disc</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Costochondritis</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Degenerative Disc Disease (DDD)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Degenerative Joint Disease (DJD)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Herniated Disc</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Lower Cross Syndrome (LSC)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Lumbar Facet Syndrome</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Muscle Spasm</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Pain from Pregnancy</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Pain from Scoliosis</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Pinched Nerve</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Rib Subluxation</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Sacroiliac (SI) Joint Pain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Sciatica</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Sprain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Strain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Thoracic Outlet Syndrome (TOS)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Upper Cross Syndrome (UCS)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Whiplash</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="Head and Neck" className="tabcontent" onClick={"openArea(event, 'Head and Neck')"} id="defaultOpenClose">
                <ul className="list">
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Neck Pain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Headaches: Tension, Migraine, & Cluster</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Bulging Disc</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Cervical Radiculopathy</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Degenerative Disc Disease (DDD)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Degenerative Joint Disease (DJD)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Ear Aches</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Herniated Disc</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Scapular Dysfunction</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Sinus Related Issues</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Sprain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Strain</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Temporomandibular Dysfunction (TMJ)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Torticollis</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Upper Cross Syndrome (UCS)</li>
                    <li><i className="icofont-circled-right"></i> Whiplash</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</section>
```

> Index.html of React file, where I have symptoms-tabs.js in which we have openArea function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <title>Kerkhoff Chiropractic in Waukee, IA</title>
  <meta name="description"
    content="Dr. Paul Kerkhoff of Kerkhoff Chiropractic is dedicated to providing exemplary chiropractic care to every family in search of improved health. We are a health care provider that focuses on disorders of the musculoskeletal system and the nervous system, and the effects of these disorders on general health." />
  <meta name=”robots” content=”index,follow” />
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" />

  <!-- Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/symptoms-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  
  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontfaceobserver/2.1.0/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <!-- Main JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/symptoms-main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/symptoms-tabs.js"></script>
  






</body>

</html>
```

> Now down here is the code of symptoms-tabs.js, where I have openArea function

```
    (function ($) {
  ("use stict");

  // Keep active tab highlighted when clicking outside of tab
  
  $("button").on("click", function () {
    $("button").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
})(jQuery);


// Desktop Area and Symptoms We Treat Tabs

function openArea(evt, areaName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(areaName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpenClose" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpenClose").click();
for (i = 0; i < openArea.length; i++) {
  var openArea = sharedowns[i];
  if (openArea.classList.contains("show")) {
    openArea.classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have got the whole concept of React **WRONG**. You are not supposed to add *your own scripts and styles* to ```index.html```. You create components and then React will take care of the rest.

Comment: @AyushGupta what should I  do now, can you please guide me with steps?

Comment: All other files which I converted from HTML to React I did the same thing and that worked, that's why I did the same for this file too

Answer (score 2):

You have written string instead of expression. no need to use `""` quotes in react.

```
<div id="Head and Neck" className="tabcontent" onClick={(event)=>openArea(event, 'Head and Neck')} id="defaultOpenClose">
```

this should help you out.

Refer here to know more about [handling events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I replace all my onClick With onClick={(event)=>openArea(event, 'Low/Mid Back')} but still not working

Comment: I got this error 'openArea' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: you should write `openArea` function

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
onClick={"openArea(event, 'Head and Neck')"}
```

to

```
onClick={event => openArea(event, 'Head and Neck')}
```

And I have noticed that you have set two ids to `div` and there are spaces in it.

**This is not a good practice and should be corrected at once.**

Comment: When i used onClick={event => openArea(event, 'Low/Mid Back')} then I got this error 'openArea' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Are you sure that you have created a method ```openArea```? Can you share the full code?

Comment: okay let me show you the full code, sir it worked in html its mean openArea is already created but not working on react

Comment: function openArea(evt, areaName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

Comment: tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  } document.getElementById(areaName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

Comment: document.getElementById("defaultOpenClose").click();
for (i = 0; i < openArea.length; i++) {
  var openArea = sharedowns[i];
  if (openArea.classList.contains("show")) {
    openArea.classList.remove("show");
  }
}

Comment: I import the js files of this page as I imported other js files in public>index.html and that operArea code exists in that js file.

Comment: @saqibdiar Share the full code in the question. Not here